# Use an if statement inside a stored procedure query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, cfstoredproc

I'm trying to convert a ColdFusion query into a stored procedure. My original query is as follows

```
UPDATE Products
SET Active = 1,
    Pounds = #lbs#,
    Ounces = #ozs#,
    Qty = #Qty#,
    PrevQty = #GetItem.Qty#,
    PrevWMQty = #GetItem.Qty#,
    PrevGoogleQty = #GetItem.Qty#,
    <cfif Cost NEQ GetItem.OurCost>
        PrevOurCost = #GetItem.OurCost#,
    </cfif>
    OurCost = #Cost#
WHERE ItemID = '#fixedItemID#'
```

As you can see I have IF statements inside my query so if certain conditions are met that it will update those fields. If those conditions are not met then it will not include them in the update.

So I would like something like this but I am not sure this is possible in a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateQty] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Products
    SET Active = 1,
        Pounds = @var1,
        Ounces = @var2,
        Qty = @var3,
        PrevQty = @var4,
        PrevWMQty = @var5,
        PrevGoogleQty = @var6,
        IF (@var7 >= @var8)
        BEGIN
            PrevOurCost = @var7,
        END
        OurCost = @var8
    WHERE ItemID = @var9
END
```

I am basically looking to pass in optional parameters and based on their value either update that field or not. I hate to have to write an individual separate query for each IF statement for every possibility. So is this even possible or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a case expression to conditionally update a column, which avoids needing to duplicate your update statement.

e.g.

```
UPDATE Products SET
    Active = 1,
    Pounds = @var1,
    Ounces = @var2,
    Qty = @var3,
    PrevQty = @var4,
    PrevWMQty = @var5,
    PrevGoogleQty = @var6,
    PrevOurCost = case when @var7 >= @var8 then @var7 else PrevOurCost end,
    OurCost = @var8
WHERE ItemID = @var9
```

Comment: so is it not possible to do this?
 `case when (@MAPRetail IS NOT NULL AND @MAPRetail > 0) then `           
            `MAPPrice = @MAPRetail,`
            `PrevMAPPrice = @MAPPrice,`
   `PrevWMMAPPrice = @MAPPrice,`
            `end`

Comment: No, because in SQL Server its a `case expression` not a `case statement` meaning that the `case expression` can only return a value not an alternative statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than 1 way to do that

You can use Case Statement

```
      UPDATE Products
      SET Active = 1,
          Pounds = @var1,
          Ounces = @var2,
          Qty = @var3,
          PrevQty = @var4,
          PrevWMQty = @var5,
          PrevGoogleQty = @var6,
          PrevOurCost = CASE WHEN @var7 >= @var8 THEN @var7 ELSE PrevOurCost END,
          OurCost = @var8
        WHERE ItemID = @var9
```

or you can use IF statement out side of the UPDATE statement

```
IF (@var7 >= @var8)
BEGIN

      UPDATE Products
      SET Active = 1,
          Pounds = @var1,
          Ounces = @var2,
          Qty = @var3,
          PrevQty = @var4,
          PrevWMQty = @var5,
          PrevGoogleQty = @var6,
          PrevOurCost = @var7,
          OurCost = @var8
        WHERE ItemID = @var9
END
ELSE
BEGIN
      UPDATE Products
      SET Active = 1,
          Pounds = @var1,
          Ounces = @var2,
          Qty = @var3,
          PrevQty = @var4,
          PrevWMQty = @var5,
          PrevGoogleQty = @var6,
          OurCost = @var8
        WHERE ItemID = @var9

END
```

Comment: Its a "case expression" not a "case statement" :)

Comment: @DaleK It is Case Statement look at the link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: @DaleK while in MS they call it Expression https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Given its T-SQL we're talking about, I guess MS have the right to name it :) the problem with calling it a statement is that people have different expectations of it, wheres knowing its an expression is clear what you can/cannot to with it.